# Connecting through xhr-polling and jsonp-polling timeout

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I tried running my socket.io program through websocket and polling, and they both work. however, when trying to run through xhr-polling, it times out. What may be a possible cause for this?

For this program, I am using socket.io 1.2.1.

```
var options = {"force new connection":true,
               "reconnect":false,
               "connect timeout":10000,
               "flash policy port":843,
               "auto connect":true,
               "path":"/sample/socket.io",
               "transports":["xhr-polling"]}

this.namespace = io.connect( 'http://localhost:8190/', options);
```

so far, my research got nothing with regards to this concern.

EDIT:

Here is a piece of the logs on the browser.

```
socket.io-client:url parse http://localhost:8190/ +0ms
socket.io.js:1284 socket.io-client ignoring socket cache for http://localhost:8190/ +0ms
socket.io.js:1284 socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +0ms
socket.io.js:1284 socket.io-client:manager opening http://localhost:8190/ +0ms
socket.io.js:3524 engine.io-client:socket creating transport "xhr-polling" +0ms
socket.io.js:1284 socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 20000 +4ms
socket.io.js:1284 socket.io-client:manager readyState opening +1ms
socket.io.js:1284 socket.io-client:manager connect_error +3ms
socket.io.js:1284 socket.io-client:manager will wait 1000ms before reconnect attempt +2ms
socket.io.js:1284 socket.io-client:manager attempting reconnect +1s
socket.io.js:1284 socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +0ms
socket.io.js:1284 socket.io-client:manager opening http://localhost:8190/ +1ms
socket.io.js:1284 socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 20000 +0ms
```

This piece of logs keeps on repeating while steadily increasing timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that this is because the Socket.IO version 1.0+ does not, in fact, allow setting a transport aside from `[websocket and polling]`. Setting polling as your transport defaults to polling-xhr unless you set the properties `forceJSONP` and/or `jsonp` to `true` in your options.

In other words, the code should be:

```
var options = {"force new connection":true,
               "reconnect":false,
               "connect timeout":10000,
               "flash policy port":843,
               "auto connect":true,
               "path":"/sample/socket.io",
               "transports":["polling"]}

this.namespace = io.connect( 'http://localhost:8190/', options);
```

also note that `'auto connect'` is now `autoConnect`, `'force new connection'` is now `forceNew`, `'connect timeout'` is now `timeout` and `'reconnect'` is now `'reconnection'`.

```
var options = {forceNew :true,
               reconnection :false,
               timeout":10000,
               "flash policy port":843,
               autoConnect:true,
               "path":"/sample/socket.io",
               "transports":["polling"]}
```